# iOS tableview, how to work with it?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am creating an iOS application for iPhone (and probably iPad). I am using the control UITableView with a storyboard, the problem that I am having is that I must do a few things and I am kinda lost.

1. The cell in the table view must have the title, subtitle and like 2 lines of text as preview (like the mail app).
2. i dont know where to write the text of the detail, if hardcoded or if theres like a file for texts.
3. I need to save favorites cells and show then in a separate tab in the bottom menu.

Comment: http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/

Comment: You should start by reading Apple's "Table View Programming Guide for iOS". It explains how to populate the cells, and how to make custom cells.

Answer (score 2):

Edgar , I highly recommend you before trying to do a solid app reading Apple's documentation, to get a complete understanding on the core concepts of delegation and data sourcing as the tables must be filled and managed thru code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Delegation.html

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath`  is the method where tableView cells are configured.So for example
cell.textLabel.text = @"some text"; or cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"example.png"]; etc.  Also refer these tutorials.[link1](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/),[link2](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-custom-cell-and-delegates/).